# SQL sub query-display all countries that are shipped a product

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Write a query to display all the countries those shipped products: Sir Rodney's Scones.

The productname 'Sir Rodney's Scones' and the countries are in different tables. this is what I have tried so far:

```
select country
from customers
where country =any (select productname
            from products
            where productname = 'Sir Rodney''s Scones'
             )
```

I know the multirow operator is wrong, but I have no idea what to replace it with. It has to be a subquery, too.

Comment: I never heard of the country *Sir Rodney's Scones* you're currently searching for :-) There must be another table with information about shipped products and you need either a three-table-join or nested Subqueries using IN (`=any` is very uncommon)

Comment: You'll get better answers if you edit your question to include the table schemas. Otherwise, we'll all just be guessing at how the data is related. Also see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you understand dnoeth's comment? Your attempted condition asks that `country` be any of the `productname` selected from another table. How can `country` be a `productname`? This is elementary logic, it has nothing to do with programming in any language. The code should always follow your plain logic; clearly here it doesn't, regardless of SQL syntax.

Comment: you guys dont recognize northwind? tsk.. tsk..

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select country
from customers
where country in (select country
            from products
            where productname  in ('xyz','pqr')
             )
```

note: you can replace 'xyz' or 'pqr' with your product names

Answer (score 0):

You can check the existence of the country in the products for the two products.

```
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM customers A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products B WHERE B.productName='Sir Rodney''s Scones'
              AND B.country=A.country);
```

Now correcting your query: your subquery should return a country instead.

```
select country
from customers
where country in (select country
            from products
            where productname='Sir Rodney''s Scones'
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should join the customer to the order details to find out what customers bought that product.  and use distinct to get the unique countries

```
  select    distinct Country
  from      Customers c
  join      Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
  join      OrderDetails od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
  join      Products p on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
  where     p.ProductName = 'Sir Rodney''s Scones'
```

or you can use the ShipCountry from the orders table.

```
  select    distinct ShipCountry
  from      Orders o
  join      OrderDetails od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
  join      Products p on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
  where     p.ProductName = 'Sir Rodney''s Scones'
```

if you require subqueries

```
  select    distinct ShipCountry
  from      Orders o
  where     o.OrderID in (
                select      OrderID 
                from        OrderDetails od
                where       od.ProductID in (
                                select      ProductID
                                from        Products p
                                where       p.ProductName = 'Sir Rodney''s Scones'
                            )
            )
```

Comment: `[Table Name]` is not valid Oracle syntax.